# OpenSeadragon navigator not showing thumbnail image

Tags: javascript, deepzoom, seadragon

I'm testing out OpenSeadragon to see how it can handle a custom tile source. I've also turned on the navigator. However the thumbnail image does not show up in the navigator. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>OpenSeaDragon (OSD) Custom Tile Sources Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="custom_tilesource" style="width: 800px; height: 600px;"></div>
<script src="libs/openseadragon/openseadragon.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var viewer = OpenSeadragon({
    showNavigator: true,
    navigatorSizeRatio: 0.25,
    id: "custom_tilesource",
    prefixUrl: "libs/openseadragon/images/",
    wrapHorizontal: false,
    tileSources: {
      height: 9425,
      width:  9426,
      tileSize: 512,
      maxLevel: 14,
      minLevel: 10,
      getTileUrl: function( level, x, y ){
        var strSources = "W3siQXR0cmlidXRlcyI6eyJPcGVyYXRpb24iOiJTdW0ifSwiSWQiOm51bGwsIlR5cGUiOiJJbWFnZSJ9LHsiQXR0cmlidXRlcyI6e30sIklkIjoiMjIwOSIsIlR5cGUiOiJJbWFnZUlkIn1d";
        var strSampleRegion = 161;

        var handlerURL = "/MultiOmyxU/handler.ashx?X=" + x + "&Y=" + y + "&Level=" + level + "&Sources=" + strSources + "&Reason=SampleRegion=" + strSampleRegion;

        return handlerURL;
      }
    }
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If anyone has had a similar problem please let me know as I am unsure as how to proceed to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. I assume it works if you use a DZI instead of a custom tilesource? Are you seeing any errors in the console? Do you have a link you can share?

I recommend posting this to the OpenSeadragon issues:

https://github.com/openseadragon/openseadragon/issues

Someone might be able to help you there.

Comment: It does indeed work correctly for a DZI tile source. There are no errors in the console. Unfortunately I'm unable to share a link as the images I'm working with are proprietary. I've added this to the OpenSeadragon issues on Github. Thanks for the help.